# What happens to data sent to NodeRed output node which is currently down?

Tags: node.js, apache-kafka, mqtt, node-red

I am currently implementing a flow on Node-RED where MQTT subscriber node sends data to a kafka producer node i.e. output node on Node-RED.

If the Kafka producer node is not able to send data in case of remote Kafka is down then what happens to the data which is pushed to the Kafka producer node from MQTT subscriber node.

I cannot afford to loose a single data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the issue by putting a "Catch" node which catches the error thrown by the kafka producer node (It throws the data also with the error in case of remote cluster unavailable). The data then can be extracted and try to send it again to a new cluster.

Answer (score 0):

That will depend on how the Kafka producer node has been written, but having had a quick look at the [src](https://github.com/fwang7/node-red-contrib-kafka-node/blob/master/kafka.js) it seams to just log an error and throw the message away if there is a problem delivering it to Kafka

There is no retry/queuing built into Node-RED it would have to be added to a given output node. The problem comes with working out what should be kept and for how long, should it be stored on disk or in memory...

Comment: I am using a multi cluster remote kafka. The use case is that once a cluster is down my node-red flow switches to another cluster immediately but I am worried about the data loss during the switching process. Is there any work around for this ?

Comment: No, if the Kafka doesn't do anything apart from log the error there is nothing that can be done. The original payload is not even passed with the error so it could not be retried with a Catch node

Comment: Do you have any suggestion to solve this issue ? storing the data in intermediary in memory cache and try to send, if error caught then trying to push the data on another cluster ? or any work around

Comment: What should be there in the catch block ? buffer and retrying is risky as if the kafka cluster will take time to come up then in that case the buffer will overflow with the data.